# Debugging socket.io using Smart Websocket Client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to manual test my websocket funcstionality.I am using socket.io and just installed a chrome to extension which allows me to connect to my server and send messages to it.
After some research I found out the sceheme that socket.io uses to send messages - `42["{event}", {data}]`
I must be doing something wrong because when I try to send this message I dont trigger my callback.
Here is my server side code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
import config from './config';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);


// URL: ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
io.on('connection', function(client: socketIo.Client){
    console.log('Client connected..');

    io.on('auth',  (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

//start our server
server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${config.port}.`);
});
```

And here is the message which I am sending to my server.
`42["auth","test"]`

Here is a screenshot aswell.
[image: Screenshot of Smart Websocket Client]

I get the message when I connect to the websocket, but I cant trigger my callback for the 'auth' command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the code wrong..

```
io.on('connection', function(socket:SocketIO.Socket){
    console.log('Client connected..');

    socket.on('auth',  (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```